# Web Audio: Make event occur at exact moment?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to make something where sound samples are chosen randomly at intervals so that the song evolves and is different each time it's listened to. HTML Audio was not sufficient for this, because the timing was imprecise, so I am experimenting with Web Audio, but it seems quite complicated. For now, I just want to know how to make a new audio file play at 16 seconds exactly, or 32 seconds, etc. I came across something like this

```
playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime + numb);
```

But as of now I cannot make it work.

```js
var audioContext = new audioContextCheck();

function audioFileLoader(fileDirectory) {
  var soundObj = {};
  soundObj.fileDirectory = fileDirectory;

  var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
  getSound.open("GET", soundObj.fileDirectory, true);
  getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  getSound.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
      soundObj.soundToPlay = buffer;
    });
  }

  getSound.send();

  soundObj.play = function(volumeVal, pitchVal) {
    var volume = audioContext.createGain();
    volume.gain.value = volumeVal;
    var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    playSound.playbackRate.value = pitchVal;
    playSound.buffer = soundObj.soundToPlay;
    playSound.connect(volume);
    volume.connect(audioContext.destination)
    playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime)
  }

  return soundObj;
};

var harp1 = audioFileLoader("IRELAND/harp1.ogg");
var harp2 = audioFileLoader("IRELAND/harp2.ogg");

function keyPressed() {
  harp1.play(.5, 2);
  harp2.start(audioContext.currentTime + 7.5);
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed, false);
```

You see I am trying to make harp2.ogg play immediately when harp1.ogg finishes. Eventually I want to be able to choose the next file randomly, but for now I just need to know how to make it happen at all. How can I make harp2.ogg play exactly at 7.5 seconds after harp1.ogg begins (or better yet, is there a way to trigger it when harp2 ends (without a gap in audio)?)  Help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As suggestion, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/onended.

Comment: Your `soundObj` object has no `start` method. I would advise making `playSound` a property of `soundObj`, this way you can access its `start` method from outside.

Comment: Great, I already know I need to study up on the fundamentals more before trying to be too ambitious --- what would "making playSound a property of soundObj" look like? Thanks!

Comment: `soundObj.source = playSound` then you can do `harp2.source.start(...)`

Answer (score 1):

WebAudio should be able to start audio very precisely using `start(time)`, down to the nearest sample time.  If it doesn't, it's because the audio data from `decodeAudioData` doesn't contain the data you expected, or it's a bug in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when you call `keyPressed`, you want to trigger both songs to start playing. One immediately, and the other in 7.5 seconds.

1. The function to play the songs is `soundObj.play` and it needs to take an additional argument, which is the audioContext time to play the song. Something like: `soundObj.play = function(volumeVal, pitchVal, startTime) {...}`
2. The `function keyPressed()` block should look something like this:

   `harp1.play(.5, 2, 0);
   harp2.start(1, 1, audioContext.currentTime + 7.5);
   audioContext.resume();`

audioContext.resume() starts the actual audio (or rather starts the audio graph timing so it does things you've scheduled)